# Temporarily suspend user from making another request

Tags: nsdate, swift3

I'm building a swift iOS-based app that limits users to submit only one request per 10 minutes.I'm suck now translating these three points to code

1- user clicks a button 
2- button is disabled for 10 minute
3- button is enabled

I'm not expecting the full code :) just a method or advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to keep the state in persistent data, incase user go to another controller and go back, the button should still disabled.

```
class PersistentData {
    static let sharedInstance = PersistentData();
    var disableSubmitButton = false
}
```

Then in your controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // each load need to check
    if PersistentData.sharedInstance.disableSubmitButton == true {
        submitButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}

func onButtonClicked() {

    // change button to disable
    submitButton.isEnabled = false

    // set state in persistent data so it can be the same wherever controller you go
    PersistentData.sharedInstance.disableSubmitButton = true

    // now set the timer to enable back
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0 * 60, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateButtonState), userInfo: nil, repeats: false);
}

func updateButtonState() {

    // update value in persitence data
    PersistentData.sharedInstance.disableSubmitButton = false

    // change button to enable back
    submitButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the following: timeInterval is in seconds so 60*10 is 10 minutes.  UI Updates need to happen on the main thread which is why the time block gets dispatched back to main.

```
    @IBAction func touchButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        button.isEnabled = false
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60*10, repeats: false) { _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.button.isEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }
```